# Adding Picasso library

Tags: android, libraries, picasso

I have some code in which I am using `view pager` to display drawables. I wanted to seek drawables from parse. For this, I am using `Picasso library`. I have placed `Picasso.jar` file in my projects `libs` folder and now I want help to implement it for my case in my class.

Here is my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three


    };
    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
```

I don't know where and how to use this line:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

My goal is to fetch images from the URL in `viewpager` instead of drawables.

Comment: replace the   imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);  with this Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);

Comment: I am seeing the same image of the URL three times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `GalImages` like below:

```
private String[] GalImages = new String[] {
    "first_url","second_url","third_url"  
}
```

load the image with `picasso` like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(GalImages[position]).into(imageView);
```

Comment: What if i put all my images in Parse, and fetch the from there , how would that be possible?

Comment: could you help me in telling how?

Comment: @EmmilieFrank uploading images to parse ? ..you can load any images from remote using picasso

Comment: No, i want to show the images in my app that are uploaded  to Parse

Comment: @EmmilieFrank then upload the images to parse.. then put the urls in the GalImages  array